# Rank a subset of data containing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to rank the following subset of data;

[image]

To achieve a rank of row 1, for the first two rows, so that it outputs similar to the below;

[image]

Here is the SQL fiddle example;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7690e/2

Comment: Why does testemailD have expected rank =1/1/4/4 ?

Comment: I want to be able to subset expectedRank = 1 - as they're the latest increment.

Comment: can you explain the logic? testemaild 1? etc. how would you do it manually?

Comment: I wanted to add a where clause down the line that says filter on records where ExpectedRank > 1

As in this instance, we have the latest version ExpectedRank = 1, which is the one i'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems like a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

You want to rank each island of emails by date. A common, if not particularly efficient, solution is to use `LAG` to check the previous row, then use a windowed conditional `COUNT` to create the numbering.

```sql
SELECT
  CustomerId,
  QuoteEmail,
  CreatedDateTime,
  OverallQuoteRank,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN PrevEmail = QuoteEmail THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      PrevEmail = LAG(QuoteEmail) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC)
    FROM temptable tt
) tt;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7690e/18)

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to be entering in pairs, you can format your `CreatedDateTime` column for *hours* and *minutes* to create a "pair key".

I wouldn't consider this solution to be perfect though since a `CreatedDateTime` value can be inserted with non-matching hour and minute values (i.e. `2022-10-11 12:30` and `2022-10-11 12:31`). You can possibly use your `OverallRank` column to create a better pair key but if I were you, I'd create a new column to use a key during your `INSERT`.

Once you establish a key, you can use `DENSE_RANK` to do the rest.

With that said, this query does suffice for your provided sample data:

```
 SELECT *, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY FORMAT(CreatedDateTime,'hh:mm') DESC, CustomerId, QuoteEmail) AS ExpectedOutcome 
      FROM temptable
    ORDER BY OverallQuoteRank DESC
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/m2M57c6J).

**Result:**

| CustomerId | QuoteEmail | CreatedDateTime | OverallQuoteRank | ExpectedOutcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99888 | testemailD@hotmail.co.uk | 2022-10-11 12:30:15.560 | 10 | 1 |
| 99888 | testemailD@hotmail.co.uk | 2022-10-11 12:30:05.297 | 9 | 1 |
| 99888 | testemailBio@gmail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:44.287 | 8 | 2 |
| 99888 | testemailBio@gmail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:43.060 | 7 | 2 |
| 99888 | testemailBio@gmail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:42.017 | 6 | 2 |
| 99888 | testemailBio@gmail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:28.853 | 5 | 2 |
| 99888 | testemailerDa@googlemail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:14.557 | 4 | 3 |
| 99888 | testemailerDa@googlemail.com | 2022-10-11 12:29:05.027 | 3 | 3 |
| 99888 | testemailD@hotmail.co.uk | 2022-10-11 12:28:39.673 | 2 | 4 |
| 99888 | testemailD@hotmail.co.uk | 2022-10-11 12:28:24.257 | 1 | 4 |